# Easy way to SELECT * with ExternalData in Mediawiki?

Tags: mysql, mediawiki, semantic-web

The [ExternalData extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:External_Data) works fine when you I the column names I am looking for, but if I don't know them in advance I look them up from information_schema and then try and fail to hack them into a new query.

Has anyone done this already or found a better way to SELECT * from an external table?

Comment: This question would use the `semantic-mediawiki` tag.

Comment: Thanks Nemo, I can't find sematic-mediawiki but have added semantic-web